# Moving contents: Can't get entire contents of path

Tags: macos, applescript

I am simply trying to move the contents of my path from one directory to another but I keep getting an error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set srcPath to POSIX path of ((parent of (path to me) as text) & "M Templates")
    set dstPath to POSIX path of (((path to movies folder) as text) & "M Templates")


    duplicate entire contents of srcPath to dstPath
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `~/Movies/M Templates` already exists, and you want to copy additional files into it rather than just replace it completely:

```
set src to path to me
set dst to path to movies folder

tell application "Finder"
  duplicate items of folder "M Templates" of parent of src ¬
      to folder "M Templates" of dst with replacing
end tell
```

(Use `duplicate...with replacing` if you want Finder to overwrite any existing items automatically.)

Or, to copy the `M Templates` folder over, replacing any previous one:

```
set src to path to me
set dst to path to movies folder

tell application "Finder"
  duplicate folder "M Templates" of parent of src to dst with replacing
end tell
```